# Computername variable in cmd

Tags: windows, variables, cmd

In CMD the following variable will give you the name of the computer: %COMPUTERNAME%

I need a variable that takes a part of the computername.

I need a if statement that checks if the computername contains "KM" at the start and 00 at the end. It should not look at the number between KM and -00

```
KM100-00
KM200-00
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you try to write some code to solve your question ?

Comment: Could you provide us some atempts of your trys to solve the problem, or what your research about solving the problem has catched so far?

Answer (score 5):

This works here:

```
echo %computername%| findstr "^KM.*00$" >nul && echo found the right format
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with substring commands, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> set xyzzy=KM100-00 KM200-00

pax> echo %xyzzy%
KM100-00 KM200-00

pax> echo %xyzzy:~0,2%
KM

pax> echo %xyzzy:~-2,2%
00

pax> if %xyzzy:~0,2%==KM if %xyzzy:~-2,2%==00 echo yes
yes
```

That final (chained) `if` statement is the one you're looking for to see if your variable starts with `KM` and ends with `00`.

The expression `%X:~Y,Z%` will give you the `Z` characters starting at position `Y` (zero-based) of the variable `X`. You can provide a negative value of `Y` to make it relative to the end of the string.

Comment: if .%COMPUTERNAME:~0,2%. == KM if .%COMPUTERNAME:~-2,2%. == 00 net use x: \\server // this work?

Comment: @Stefan, not sure why you have `.` characters around your `COMPUTERNAME`. If they're to prevent problems in the event `COMPUTERNAME` doesn't exist then you'll need them around `KM` and `00` as well. And, yes, the `if` statements should work, I can't comment on your `net use` :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo %computername%| findstr /I /b "KM" | findstr /i /e "00" && echo computer name is like KM-XX-00
```

You can try also with `hostname` instead of `echo %computername%`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read [this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), which is about substring usage in command prompt.

And why dont you try this;

```
set str=KM2000-00
echo.%str%

set pre=%str:~0,2%
echo.%pre%

set pst=%str:~-2%
echo.%pst%

IF %pre% == KM( IF %pst% == 00( echo.true ) )

pause
```